# Visual Studio 2015 taking too much time to start

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual studio 2015 Enterprise, but it taking too much time to start (5~7 minutes).

Here is some feature I installed:

> Architecture and Modeling Tools 
>   Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools 
>   LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015 
>   Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015 
>   Visual Basic 2015 
>   Visual C# 2015 
>   Visual C++ 2015 
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0 
>   ASP.NET and Web Tools 
>   ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013 
>   Common Azure Tools   1.5 
>   GenerateUnitTest 
>   GitHub.VisualStudio 
>   Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools 
>   Microsoft Code Digger 
>   Microsoft.Pex.VisualStudio 
>   NuGet Package Manager 
>   Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU 
>   PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer 
>   SQL Server Data Tools 
>   Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 
>   Xamarin 
>   Xamarin.Android 
>   Xamarin.iOS 
>   Xamarin.TestCloud.Integration

How can I reduce the time to lauch it?

Comment: You could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what's actually happening on disk etc.

Comment: @UweKeim Thank you for your comment, I have resolved this problem, seems some features of mobile component take much time to load. I have removed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the components you've installed, the visual studio may take time to load/start. However it is always depend on the specs of your computer and if there are other applications running that affects the process of your workstation.

Some tips:

Remove features that you don't need, like if your not going to develop mobile application, you can temporarily remove `Xamarin` `Xamarin.Android` `Xamarin.iOS` `Xamarin.TestCloud.Integration`. Just temporarily remove the features of VS2015 that you dont need, then you can add it back when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have removed some features of mobile component. And the time to start is reduced, seems that features take much time to load.

Comment: Yup, it will load all installed components when you open the VS2015 , removing what you don't need for your development is a big help.

Comment: Any details on how to remove unwanted components?